# how to properly display new date data from json record in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the code below which works fine and display date data in the following format eg.
**Thu Dec 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)** when alerted and its working fine

```
$(document).ready(async function(){

function rec(el, data, settings){

var obj = data;
console.log(obj);
}

var events = [
  {'Date': new Date(2023, 10, 28), 'Title': 'title 1'},
  {'Date': new Date(2023, 11, 28), 'Title': 'title 2'},
  {'Date': new Date(2022, 12, 27), 'Title': 'title 3'},
];
// alert date sample
alert(events[0].Date);

var settings = {};
var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
rec(element, events, settings);

});
```

**Here is my issue:**

Now I need to display the record by making fetch API call to php backend as per code below
but when i run the code and alert eg `alert(events[0].Date);`  am getting something like  **new Date(2023, 10, 28)** instead of  **Thu Dec 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)**

PleaseI need all my Date in the following format eg. **Thu Dec 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)**

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(async function(){

function rec(el, data, settings){
var obj = data;
console.log(obj);
}

const response = await fetch('http://localhost/record.php', {
    method: 'GET'
});

var events = await response.json();
alert(events[0].Date);

var settings = {};
var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
rec(element, events, settings);

});
```

here is **record.php**

```
/*
$return_arr = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM usera";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $Date = $row['Date'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    $return_arr[] = array(
                    "Date" => $Date,
                    "Title" => $title,
                    "Link" => $link);
}

// Encoding array in JSON format
 json_encode($return_arr);
*/

    $arr = array(
        array(
            "Date" => "new Date(2023, 10, 28)",
            "Title" => "title 1"
        ),
        array(
            "Date" =>  "new Date(2023, 11, 28)",
            "Title" => "title 2"
        ),
        array(
               "Date" =>  "new Date(2023, 11, 28)",
            "Title" => "title 3"
        )
    );
    
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: you are passing `new Date(2023, 10, 28)` back in the JSON response? That will be a string at that point and will NOT have been processed by JS to actually create a valid Date object... send back a string that can be loaded, in JS, to create the date itself. It would be useful to know precisely the format of the dates stored in your `usera` table

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks for your response.  since backend record is fetched via
`var events = await response.json();`  how do i dynamicaly  add `.toString()` to all Date Records before passing it to **events** variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly display date data from a JSON record in JavaScript, modify your PHP backend to format dates as strings in a standard format. In the PHP code:

```
    $Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['Date']));
    $title = $row['title'];
    // rest...
```

In JavaScript, parse the date strings into JavaScript Date objects:

```
    var events = await response.json();
    events.forEach(event => {
        event.Date = new Date(event.Date);
    });
    // rest...
```